# MYSQL TEXT datatype to string and vice versa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Hi I have a table with TEXT datatype. I am using hibernate to fetch/insert data.

My problem is like

1. What datatype should I use in my entity class object for TEXT type?
2. How to convert TEXT data to string and vice versa.
3. Is there any alternative to TEXT datatype? I need to insert a large text(string) to this column.

Answer (score 1):

1. Unsure of the question.
2. Cast string to it? I'm not sure how you have decided to retrieve the data but it should be  String s = (String) textdata;
3. BIG TEXT or Varchar

Comment: Varchar has 255 char limit.I need more. I tried to use it as a string for inserting and retrieving values. No errors are thrown ut not inserting any values into database.

Comment: Use big text then, it has a ridiculous size and it is almost the same as entering in text. Big Text is a String so converting shouldn't be needed with the proper sql code, if you would share the code you have currently that isn't working I may be able to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.What datatype should I use in my entity class object for TEXT type?

*Answer*

```
java.lang.String
```

> 2.How to convert TEXT data to string and vice versa.

*Answer*

It is already `String` no need to convert.

> 3.Is there any alternative to TEXT datatype? I need to insert a large text(string) to this column.

*Answer*

You can store up to length `65535`

- [hibernate mapping types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_types.htm)

---

For `.hbm.xml` file

```
<property name="property" type="string">
  <column name="column" length="65535" />
</property>
```

You can generate `.java` and `.hbm.xml` through [hibernate code generation tool for eclipse](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.1.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/#plugins)

---

For annotation

```
@Column(name = "COLUMNNAME", length = 65535)
```